# how to save Login enry to a XML file

Tags: c#, .net, xml, io

i am creating a Simple Login form in C# Windows Form .Net 2.0, And i want to save login Name or Password to Xml file so that once i submit the username or password i don't have to put the same username or password in "textbox" again instead it should show the username or password in "textbox" that i have submited before, just like we save our username or passwords for "gmail, yahoo, facebook, ect." and it shows us our saved username or password in "Login" form so we don't have to put our username or passwords again.

Answer (score 1):

Even simpler way, just use XmlSerializer to do your loading/unloading.

```
public class User
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public void SaveUser(User user)
{
    var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(User));
    using(var file = File.OpenWrite(@"c:\myfilepath\user.xml")) 
    {
        ser.Serialize(file, user);
    }
}

public User GetUser(string xmlFile)
{
    var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(User));
    User user;
    using (var file = File.OpenRead(xmlFile))
    {
        user = (User)ser.Deserialize(file);
    }
    return user;
}
```

If you want to save collection of users, just serialize on a collection type, e.g. `List<User>.` That will save all users in xml, as well as retrieve them all into a `List<User>` all at once.

Comment: what i want is (Click to see on these links):- http://i49.tinypic.com/rkuats.jpg and http://i46.tinypic.com/21edys1.jpg

Comment: Sorry, screenshot doesn't explain what you want. Are you referring to auto-completion? Thats completely a different issue all together. Your original question was based on user/password data saving.

Comment: sorry i don't know about AutoComplete but what i want is in the screen shoot do you have solution for this

Comment: I am not understanding your question from the screenshot. All it is couple of text boxes for username password. I don't see what it is that you asking about. I don't you will get an answer just from that screenshot, you will have to elaborate your question.

Comment: what i want to achieve is:- imagine u have 2 or more account at gmail. when you insert your username or password and sign in it asks for save your username or password and if you save your username or password u don't have to put yoour username or password every time because it shows your username or password in login textbox like i provide in screen shoot. Exactly this is i want do with my login application, Once if i submit it should show username or password and when i click on username it Autocomplete username or password

Answer (score 0):

To read User ID & Password From Xml file:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(@"c:\test\user.xml");
        XmlNode nodeUserId = doc.SelectSingleNode("/user/UserID");
        XmlNode nodePassword = doc.SelectSingleNode("/user/Password");

        textBox1.Text = nodeUserId.InnerText;
        textBox2.Text = nodePassword.InnerText;
```

To save the UserID & Password back to Xml file:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(@"c:\test\user.xml");
        XmlNode nodeUserId = doc.SelectSingleNode("/user/UserID");
        XmlNode nodePassword = doc.SelectSingleNode("/user/Password");

        nodeUserId.InnerText = textBox1.Text;
        nodePassword.InnerText = textBox2.Text;

        doc.Save(@"c:\test\user.xml");
```

Comment: what i want is (Click to see on these links):- http://i49.tinypic.com/rkuats.jpg and http://i46.tinypic.com/21edys1.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following article which explains how to create an AutoComplete Extender for your text box:

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article225.aspx